# iterator operations not working

Tags: c++, iterator

For some reason in this function where it counts "clumps" of two or more of the same value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> 
#include <set>

int countClumps(multiset<int> set)
{
    int clumps = 0;

    for (multiset<int>::const_iterator iter(set.begin()), end(set.end()); iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if (iter == iter[1] && iter != iter[-1])
        {
            clumps += 1;
        }
    }
    return clumps;
}
```

I get the error "no operator '[]' matches these operands". Why would this happen? I thought stuff like iter[i] and *(iter + i) were standard operations? I did try *(iter + 1) but that gave me the same operand error but with +. Was there something that I've forgotten to include?

Answer (score 4):

> I get the error "no operator '[]' matches these operands". Why would this happen?

That's because `operator[]` is not supported on `multiset<int>::const_iterator`.

> I thought stuff like `iter[i]` and `*(iter + i)` were standard operations?

You thought wrong.

> I did try `*(iter + 1)` but that gave me the same operand error but with `+`. Was there something that I've forgotten to include?

`operator+` is not supported between a `multiset<int>::const_iterator` and an `int`. Hence, `iter + 1` is not a valid expression.

You haven't forgotten to include anything. You are trying operations that are not supported on the type of the object.

You will have to rethink your code.

---

Something along the lines of the following implementation should work.

```
int countClumps(multiset<int> set)
{
   int clumps = 0;
   int previousNumber = 0;

   multiset<int>::const_iterator iter(set.begin());
   multiset<int>::const_iterator end(set.end());

   // Account for empty input.
   if ( iter != end )
   {
      previousNumber = *iter;

      for (++iter; iter != end; )
      {
         if ( previousNumber == *iter )
         {
            ++clumps;

            // Skip the rest of the clump
            for ( ++iter; iter != end && previousNumber == *iter ; ++iter );
         }
         else
         {
            ++iter;
         }

         if ( iter != end )
         {
            previousNumber = *iter;
         }

      }
   }
   return clumps;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::multiset` has a bidirectional iterator. You may not use `operator []` and `operator +` with this iterator. Use standard functions `std::next` and `std::prev` instead to get a previous or next iterator..

Also you should compare values pointed to by iterators instead of the iterators themselves.

Take into account that it would be much better if the parameter is declared like reference.

The function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

size_t countClumps( std::multiset<int> &set )
{
    size_t clumps = 0;

    for ( auto first = set.begin(), last = set.end(); first != last; )
    {
        auto value = *first;
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( ++first != last && *first == value ) ++i;

        if ( i ) ++clumps;
    }

    return clumps;
}

int main() 
{
    std::multiset<int> set { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5 };

    std::cout << countClumps( set ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

Comment: That helps a ton, thanks! Actually I tried comparing directions after comparing values didn't work at first so that was just me going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @BaloneyOs See also a demonstrative program in my answer.:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an `std::multiset<>::const_iterator` is a [`bidirectional_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/), which does not support the dereference operator, unlike the [`random_access_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/).

You could do something like this:

```
if (set.length() > 2)
    for (multiset<int>::const_iterator iter(std::next(set.begin())), end(std::prev(set.end())); iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if (*iter == *std::next(iter) && *iter != *std::prev(iter))
        {
            clumps += 1;
        }
    }
```

But your algorithm is still wrong... I'd do (not tested):

```
bool first_time = true;
bool in_clump = false;
int prev_val;
for (auto element: set)
{
    if (first_time)
    {
        prev = element;
        first_time = false;
    }
    else if (element == prev)
    {
        if (!in_clump)
        {
            ++clumps;
            in_clump = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        in_clump = false;
    }
}
```